# Testing duplicates with assert

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, assertions

```
  public void HStringTest(String[] SArray){
        HashSet<String> F = new HashSet<String>();
        for(String aryElement : stringArray){
            if(!F.add(aryElement)){
                System.out.println("Duplicate" + aryElement);
            }
        }

    }
```

To test above I simply called the method in a different class under @Test.
Runs just fine but how do I assert the test?

Comment: You would need to replace `System.out` with an alternative `PrintStream` for which you can capture everything written to it.

Comment: Unrelated: please read about java naming conventions, and about "naming" in general. `F` is a really horrible name for a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler test:

```
assertThat(sArray.length, is( ( new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(sArray)).size() );
```

In other words: simply **turn** your array into a Set; and then check that the array and the set have the same number of entries.

( where *is* is a [hamcrest](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/11/hamcrest-matchers-tutorial.html) matcher )

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `assert f.add(aryEelement);` or use `org.junit.Assert` for a testing class:

```
@Test
public void HStringTest(String[] sArray){
    HashSet<String> f = new HashSet<String>();
    for(String aryElement : sArray){
        Assert.assertTrue("Duplicate " + aryElement, f.add(aryElement));
    }
}
```

Hint: due to naming conventions variables starts with a small letter

Comment: I'm using page object model and I created object of the method containing class. eg somePractice practice = new SomePractice(); and crated string array:- String[] SArray = new String[] {"a", "b"}; @Test public void test(){ practice.HStringTest(SArray) }

Comment: @shilpa that's not how tests should be designed ;) Why a test class invokes a testing method of another class?

Comment: I'm using page object model. :)

Comment: @shilpa ok, now I got it. Is it possible to change the return type of the testing method? Let's say to `boolean` and return the success flag.

Comment: No, that's not possible. I won't be able to use annotations.